# Addition operator before a variable

Tags: c

```
main()
{
int i=-1;
+i;
printf("%d %d",i,+i);
}
```

What is the function of +?The output given in the book is -1 -1.

Comment: `+i` is using the unary plus operator, which doesn't do addition. During the standardization process, there was a time during which the unary plus operator did something, but by the time the standard was finished, its functionality had been removed (but the operator itself remained).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: The unary plus operator sometimes _does_ do something, as in `char c; printf("%d %d\n", sizeof c, sizeof +c);` (as I'm sure you know, and of course this is inappropriate for helping a beginner).

Answer (score 2):

You might just think of `-i` or `+i` the same as `0-i` or `0+i`.  If `i` is negative, then `-i` is positive, while `+i` doesn't change the value.

Answer (score 2):

That's a unary +. It's essentially a no-op. The book is correct. (Why did you think it wasn't?)

Answer (score 1):

It is essentially an identity in the book's case (and the book is correct). The concept makes it easier to represent certain complex number operations. That is also why you can have a `-0`. That is, consider approaching 0 from `1` or `-1` at small increments.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no difference in value of +i and i. +i is just as 0+i. -i changes the value to -1*i or 0-i.

Comment: so if -i was given there would still not be any change right?

Comment: @SayandeepMitra no it gives the value that is -1 multiplied to that value.

Answer (score 0):

`+i` evaluates to `i`. `-i` would evaluate to `i` negated. In any case, the value of `i` remains unchanged; i.e. outside of an assignment or comparison, it's a no-op. The compiler *should* give you a warning about this.

Comment: 'return value'? I think a better wording would be 'evaluates to'.

Comment: @ajay: If `i` were of type `MyClass` instead of `int`, we would be talking about the return value of `operator+()`... but you are right of course, "evaluates to" is more appropriate here.